# Can't install eclipse IDE - JRE missing. Can't open file

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, installation

I'm trying to install eclipse on a windows 10 laptop, so downloaded the installer however when I try to run it I get the following error open in Chrome:

[image: java]

I've seen people saying I need to install oracle jdk, so I've done that (jdk-11.0.2) but I'm still getting this error. 
Does anybody know how I might fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which JDK do you have? x64 or x86?

Comment: java SE development kit 11. it was the most recent one on their downloads page. x64

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787980/8809524 Check if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you help everyone, in the end I solved it by installing a slightly older version of the JDK instead of the latest one. This seems to have fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Would need more information as to what operating system you are running. I have seen instances where users are having trouble installing in an old Java class and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603276/8008686) worked for them.

"Solution: Download & install the Windows-x64-version of the Java Development Kit instead of the Windows-x86-version."
[image]

Also make sure that you are utilizing the same bit Eclipse installer as your JRE or you would encounter an error such as this.

You can also specify the location of the JRE (again, be sure they are the same bit) by utilizing [these steps](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it's windows 10

Comment: Are you using the same bit Eclipse Installer and JRE? (ie. 64 or 32)?

Comment: They're both 64bit

Comment: Still trying to dig into this and found [this reference](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1071877/) if you have not seen it yet. The user said they were able to solve the problem by removing everything and installing both at 32-bit (regardless that they are on a 64-bit system). You van also specify the JRE location for Eclipse using [these steps](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to solve it be installing a different version of the JDK (the version before) and that's worked. Not sure why the latest one wouldn't work.............

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have JAVA_HOME set properly.
Try setting it by following [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10/amp&ved=2ahUKEwjq5sq14afgAhWJuo8KHfLtA9YQFjAHegQIDRAi&usg=AOvVaw2EJPk9XIZYmJjEjDE4MDrd&ampcf=1) link.

Comment: I've done this and am still getting the same error. I did notice, however, that the JDK was installed in program files x86, despite me not having the x86 JDK. Not sure if that'll be an issue?

Comment: You should also make sure that you are installing correct jdk wrt ur system configuration i.e 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Double checked and I'm definitely on a 64 bit OS, so that should be ok?

Comment: x86 is for 32bit.. since you have 64bit OS you need to uninstall and install again the appropriate version of jdk and don't forget to set environment variables